# Error while parsing ics for caldav

Tags: icloud, icalendar, ical-dotnet

iCal .net version -: 2.3.3
I am getting following error while parsing ics using ical .Net -:

```
expecting "END", found '105'
expecting "END", found '1047'
expecting "END", found '102'
expecting "END", found '1000'
expecting "END", found '1'
expecting "END", found '"'
expecting "COLON", found '.'
expecting "COLON", found ','
expecting "COLON", found ' '
expecting "COLON", found '  '
```

This is happening only on few accounts/events.

Comment: You'll need to post your ics text.

Comment: ICS is too long so sharing link that has ics https://pastebin.com/tG7dbZpn

Comment: Exception type is antlr.MismatchedTokenException

Comment: Ical has line breaks (`\r\n`) as tokens delimiting calendar elements. Your ics text doesn't have any. It's completely malformed, which is one of the reasons it can't be parsed.

Comment: It has \r\n but when I logged the ics it replaces \r\n to space.

Comment: ICS is completely fine as it is returned by caldav server.
Check this https://pastebin.com/Cmpwyrzd

Comment: I can assure you your CalDAV server has bugs, and is not a reliable source of truth for what is or isn't valid ICS text. Your second ICS text is better, but still malformed: it's the line beginning with `X-APPLE-STRUCTURED-LOCATION`. It looks like improper line folding: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5545#section-3.1

Comment: The ics is returned by apple's caldav server.
Base Server URL -: https://pxx-caldav.icloud.com. I don't think apple gives wrong ics.

Comment: The ICS you've pasted is malformed: it's not folded properly. Per the ical spec, lines are limited to 80 octets. No exceptions. It doesn't matter where the ics text originated from. There's no "if Apple" allowance in the RFC. See the URL I pasted above if you don't believe me. Or, you can upgrade to Ical.NET 3+, and this line will parse, because it's more a more forgiving parser in some cases.

Comment: Apple doesn't serialize locations properly: https://github.com/rianjs/ical.net/issues/348

Comment: Thanks. I am checking this and will back to you. Do apple have dev forum for caldav server support? I am not able to find. Can you point me to that?

Answer (score 0):

Apple's ical stuff is more broken than most. They fail to serialize at least 2 things properly:

- [UTC offsets](https://github.com/rianjs/ical.net/issues/245)
- [Locations](https://github.com/rianjs/ical.net/issues/348)

Your particular problem is with a location. I think ical.net versions 3+ will handle the location deserialization without dying. The v3 parser is more forgiving in some cases than the v2 (ANTLR-based) parser.

I'm not sure if I'm going to add in Apple-specific ics handling; they really should fix their bugs, but they probably won't.

Comment: I have installed ical.Net 4.0.6 in my project but I am facing some issues. Initially I got error that system can't find file System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives, Version=4.1.1.0, which I have solved by installing it. But after that I am getting error 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Reflection.TypeExtensions, Version=4.0.0.0'. I have tried to install it but it is not installing as I am using .net framework 4.5.2 and it can't be installed in this framework. I have installed version 4.4.0 but it is not helping as ica.net is expecting version 4.0.0.

Comment: Hi, I think v4 is missing some dependencies. Can you please check and let me know?
Might be same as -:
1) https://github.com/rianjs/ical.net/issues/324
2) https://github.com/rianjs/ical.net/issues/326
Thanks

Comment: Hi rianjs,
    Any suggestions ?

Comment: It’s this issue which is a .NetStandard problem. https://github.com/rianjs/ical.net/issues/353 You’ll need to follow the workarounds given by Microsoft that I linked there.